# C# How to call something from within a class method

Tags: c#

I have some code that produces this compiler error:

> **CS0236** A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'PublicModule.rnd'

The code is below, with the line with the error marked:

```
public class PublicModule : ModuleBase
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int value = rnd.Next(4,50); // <<<< Error is here

    [Command("Ping")]
    public async Task ping()
    {
       await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + ", Pong!");
    }

    [Command("Hara")]
    public async Task hara()
    {
        await ReplyAsync("Hara noi te iubim <3 .");
    }

    [Command("kek")]
    public async Task kek()
    {
        await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + ", kek");
    }

    [Command("Random")]
    public async Task Dice()
    {
        await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + " ur random number is : " + value);
    }
}
```

How can I call that `rnd.Next` from a class? I'm noob at coding and I don't know how can I call things from another class or function etc.

Comment: You need to put the `rnd.Next` inside a function body. You can't write statements outside functions in C#. Move the `int value = rnd.Next();` statement into the `Dick()` before showing the value.

Comment: please try to put the code in the question it will be more easier to help

Comment: I suggest you start by going through a C# tutorial. There are dozens of tutorials for beginners.

Comment: It is considered ***extremely*** rude here to post an image instead of the text for your code. You get one mulligan (I fixed it for you). Don't do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the statement `int value = rnd.Next();` from the class and move it to the function `Dick()` as follows:

```
public async Task Dice()
{
    int value = rnd.Next(4, 50);
    await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + "ur random number is: " + value);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure did :P. That's changed now.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the constructor:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int value;

public PublicModule()
{
    value = rnd.Next(4,50); 
}
```

But I should also point out that this will only give you a new random number once per class instance. If you want a different random number every time you call the function, you should do it like this:

```
[Command("Random")]
public async Task Dice()
{
    int value = rnd.Next(4,50);
    await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + " ur random number is : " + value);
}
```